# Clarifying Stokes' Theorem misconceptions with a problem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Question: Using Stokes's Theorem for $A=(y+z)\hat i-(xz) \hat j+(y^2)\hat k$ where $S$ is the surface of the region in the first octant bounded by $2x+z=6$ and $y=2$ which is not included in the (a) $xy$ plane, (b) the plane $2x+z=6$.

I can't seem to get the answer in the textbook.

First I evaluated $\nabla$ x $A$

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \\
    y+z & -xz & y^2 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

Which gave me:
$\nabla$ x $A$= $(2y+x) \hat i+ \hat j + (1-z) \hat k$

Now in my mind the surface I'm supposed to integrate over looks something like this, which can be divided into 5 surfaces:

---

[image]

I'm quite new to Stokes' Theorem, so do correct me if I have any conceptual errors.

For the 2 triangle surfaces, I started calculating for one of the surfaces first.

$$\hat n= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\int \int_R  \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}. \begin{pmatrix}
    2y+x\\
    1\\
    1-z \\
    \end{pmatrix}dx dz=\int \int_R 1 dx dz = 9 $$

Since the surface integral of the curl of A is independent of $x,y,z$, both triangle surfaces give the same value. (ie. 9)

For the surface lying on the $yz$ plane

$$\hat n= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\int \int_R  \begin{pmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}. \begin{pmatrix}
    2y+x\\
    1\\
    1-z \\
    \end{pmatrix}dy dz=\int_0 ^6 \int_0 ^2 (2y+x) dy dz = 24 (x=0) $$

For the surface on the $xy$ plane:

$$\hat n= 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\int \int_R  \begin{pmatrix}
    0\\
    0\\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}. \begin{pmatrix}
    2y+x\\
    1\\
    1-z \\
    \end{pmatrix}dx dy=\int \int_R (1-z) dx dy = 6 (z=0) $$

For the plane surface:
Let $f=2x+z$

$\nabla f= \begin{pmatrix}
    2\\
    0\\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

For this surface, I didn't bother finding $\hat n dS$ as from my understanding, $\hat n dS=\nabla f dxdy$

$$\int \int_R  \begin{pmatrix}
    2\\
    0\\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}. \begin{pmatrix}
    2y+x\\
    1\\
    1-z \\
    \end{pmatrix}dx dy=\int \int_R (4y+2x-z+1) dx dy$$

Subbing in  $-z=2x-6$
$$\int_0 ^2 \int_0 ^3 (4y+4x-5) dx dy=-42$$

Adding all of them up, $9.2+24+6-42=6$

a) Subtracting $xy$ plane $6-6=0$

b) Subtracting the plane surface $2x+z=6, 6+42=48$.

The answer in my textbook is $-6 and -18$ respectively. I'm not really concerned about the answer here, but I think I have several misconceptions of Stokes' theorem even after studying when its applicability. I'd be grateful if someone can point out any misconceptions I have here (hence the typing of this long working). Thanks.

Comment: The curl of $\mathbf A$ should be $(x + 2 y, 1, -z - 1)$.

The surfaces are oriented; outward normals to the two triangular faces have opposite directions, making those two integrals cancel out.

Computing the gradient is fine because essentially you have the parametrization $\mathbf r = (u, v, f(u, v))$ for the surface $z = f(x, y)$, then $d \mathbf S = \mathbf r_u \times \mathbf r_v = \nabla(z - f(x, y))$.

Taking outward normals, you should get $I_{x = 0} = -24, \;I_{z = 0} = 6, \;I_{2 x + z = 6} = 18$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out

Comment: Except, of course, since I wrote $d \mathbf S$ first, it should have been $d \mathbf S = (\mathbf r_u \times \mathbf r_v) du dv = \nabla (z - f(x, y)) du dv$.